# Understanding const operator

Tags: c++, constants

I'm reading Scott Meyers' book and come across the following example:

```
class Rational { ... };
const Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);

Rational a, b, c;
...
(a * b) = c; // invoke operator= on the
// result of a*b!
```

He said that it was really wierd thing, but I didn't see why. What's wrong with the invokation of the `operator=` on the result of `a*b`?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with doing that, but it's very likely not to be intended. So this is a question of how much you want to help the programmer avoid silly mistakes.

Comment: @Kerrek y u write answer in comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of `a*b` is a temporary value, which will disappear at the end of the statement. Assigning to it would be weird, since you wouldn't be able to do anything with it after the assignment.

However, the fact that it's weird doesn't necessarily justify adding more weirdness to prevent it. In modern C++, it's a bad idea to return a `const` object like this since it inhibits move semantics.

Comment: So it's not an lvalue. Why  could it appear at the left hand side of the = operator ever?

Comment: @St.Antario: Because, for class types like this, `operator=()` is a member function, and you can call member functions on _rvalues_.

Comment: @St.Antario: The restriction to have lvalues on the LHS of `=` applies to the built-in `=` operations (i.e. not `operator=` calls in user-defined types), not to literally any utterance of the symbol.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d10a8c5cf66d504 Couldn't you explain what compiler's trying to say by that message. __error: passing 'const Rational' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers__ I was confused by discarding qualifiers...

Comment: @St.Antario: It means the assignment is trying to call the non-`const` member function `operator=()` on a `const` object - doing so would discard the `const` qualifier, which isn't allowed. The `const` prevents the assignment, which is why Meyers suggested it (long before move semantics made it a bad idea).

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've read about operators in the 13.5.3 chapter of the current standard and it's not quite clear how making const of the return value affects the move semantic. Couldn't you give a little explanation or point me out to the paragraph in the standard?

Comment: @St.Antario Moving from an object might change it, and you can't change a constant. Therefore you can't move from a constant, only copy it.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong or weird is that the operator= is invoked on a object which will be destructed at the end of the statement (ie at `;`).