# How does making a return value const affect move semantics?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

For instance:

```
class Rational
{
public: 
    const Rational operator*(Rational){ return Rational(); }
}
```

It was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487884/understanding-const-operator/30487981#30487981) answer but it didn't explain how it actually affects the move semantic. Couldn't you give some example?

Comment: Is there some part of "it inhibits move semantics" that was unclear?

Comment: This should be a comment to the quoted answer, not a separate question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Dont think so, because it's all about move semantic...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
Rational a, b, c;
a = b*c;
```

If `operator*` returns a non-const `Rational`, then the return value of `b*c` can be *moved* into `a`, as the value is not `const` and can be modified. The move assignment operator `operator=(Rational&&)` will be invoked.

If `operator*` returns `const Rational`, then the return value of `b*c` can't be *moved* into `a`, as the value is `const` and cannot be modified; instead it must be *copied* into `a`.  The copy assignment operator `operator=(const Rational&)` will be invoked.

If `Rational` is expensive to copy but cheap to move, then returning a `const Rational` is therefore less efficient than returning a non-const `Rational`.

Comment: Why can't we move it? What's wrong with the invocation of `operator=(const Rational&&)`?

Comment: A **move assignment** or **move construction** requires moving data from the source object into the target object and **modifying the source object** so it does not refer to that data anymore.  A `const` object cannot be modified, and thus cannot be moved from, only copied from.

Comment: @buttifulbuttefly So, during the overload resolution proccess the constness's taken into account. Am I right?

Comment: A question from this beginner what will be the return value of `b*c` I mean only c is passed to the overloaded `*` operator implementation. I am asking from the operator overloading perspective how will `b` come in to picture in this case.

Comment: @yanivx What that got to do with it?\

Comment: @St.Antario It is for my learning , I just did not understand how will `b` come in to picture when we do `b*c` using the overloaded `*` operator

Comment: @yanivx Do you understand that `b*c` is equivalent to `b.operator*(c)`? If so, it won't be a problem to understand what you're asking about.